# The difference between the nonlocal and local conditions problems

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

In some problems involving ordinary differential equations, subsidiary conditions are imposed locally. In some other cases, nonlocal conditions are imposed.

In this paper: [Existence and uniqueness of a classical solution to a functional-differential abstract nonlocal Cauchy problem](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijsa/1999/957201/abs/) Byszewski studied this form of functional-differential **nonlocal** problem:

> $(1)\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  u'(t)=f(t,u(t),u(a(t))),\:\:t\in I \\ 
>  u(t_0)+\sum_{k=1}^{p}c_ku(t_k)=x_0 
> \end{matrix}\right.$
>
> With $I:=[t_0,t_0+T], t_0<t_1<...<t_p\leq t_0+T, T>0$ and $f:I\times E^2\rightarrow E \:$ and $\:a:I\rightarrow I \:$are given functions satisfying some assumptions; $E$ is a Banach space with norm $\:\left \| . \right \|;  x_0\in E, c_k\neq 0 \:\:(k=1,...,p)\: p \in \mathbb N$.

And here, in the classical Robin problem: $$u''(t) + f(t,u(t),u'(t)) = 0$$

> With **local** conditions: $u(0)= 0$ and $u'(1) = 0.$

Or

> With **nonlocal** conditions: $u(0)= 0$ and $u(1) = u(\eta)\;\:\eta\in(0,1)$

My question is:

-When we say that The conditions of functional-differential problem are **local** or **nonlocal**?

-In which situation we impose **local** or **nonlocal** conditions?

*Thank you!*

Comment: It appears that in Byszewski's paper you mention the adjective *nonlocal* refers to an **initial** value problem, not to a boundary value problem.

Comment: I quote Byszewski: *The functional-differential nonlocal problem, studied in this paper is of the form:
...*

Comment: In your question you ask about **boundary** value problems, whereas in the quoted paper by Byszewski the word *boundary* never appears.

Comment: I edited my post, I thought that the term local, nonlocal is related to the conditions at the boundary!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but rather an extended comment.

The derivative in its ordinary sense is *local*: for any neighborhood of $x$, if $f \equiv g$ on that neighborhood and $f^{(n)}(x)$ exists then $g^{(n)}(x)$ exists and $f^{(n)}(x) = g^{(n)}(x)$. So, equations of the form
$$
x^{(n)}(t) = F(t, x(t), x'(t), \dots, x^{(n-1)}(t))
$$
or
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t, x) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(t,x) + F(t, x, u(t, x))
$$
are referred to as local.

Generally, *nonlocal* denotes that in an equation in question there is something that does not belong to the above category.  For instance, we can replace in an ODE the derivative by a derivative of fractional order:  the latter does not have the locality property as described in the first paragraph.

Equations of the form
$$
x'(t) = F(t, x(t), x(a(t))),
$$
where $a$ is a given function, are, to the best of my knowledge, (almost) never called nonlocal: the standard name appears to be (functional) (ordinary) *differential equations with deviating argument* (*retarded* or *delayed* if $a(t) < t$, and advanced if $a(t) > t$).

The boundary conditions considered in Byszewski's paper look like "usual" multipoint boundary conditions.

It seems that the author just chose to call problems considered by him *functional-differential nonlocal problems*.  I think it would be proper to ask him directly: ludwik.byszewski@pk.edu.pl.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give another example, a very classical one. Consider a smooth open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $T$ be a smooth vector field tangential to the boundary $\partial\Omega$. The Oblique Derivative Problem is
$$
\begin{cases}
∆ u=0\quad\text{in $\Omega$,}\\
Tu+\alpha \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=g\quad\text{on $\partial\Omega$,}
\end{cases}
\tag{1}$$
where $\alpha$ is a given function on the boundary.
When $T=0$ and $\alpha =1$, you recognize the Neumann problem. If you add  a zeroth-order term $\beta$ to $T$ and make $T=0$, $\alpha =0, \beta=1$, you find the Dirichlet problem.
Now you consider the Green operator $G$ you have solving uniquely the Dirichlet problem
$$
∆ Gw=0, \quad u_{\vert\partial \Omega}=w,
$$
so that $(1)$ is equivalent to 
$$
Aw:=Tw+\alpha  \frac{\partial Gw}{\partial \nu}=g,
\tag{2}$$
on $\partial\Omega$. The operator $A$ is a first-order pseudo-differential operator on the boundary and,  if $\alpha$ is not identically vanishing, is not a differential operator.
It is not difficult to see that if $\alpha$ is non-vanishing, the operator $A$ is elliptic. If you assume that at points where $\alpha$ vanishes, the vector $T$ is non-vanishing, then it implies that $A$ is principal type. Of course $A$ is a non-local operator, namely
$$
\text{support } A u\not\subset\text{support }  u
$$ 
in general. Most boundary problems are in fact non-local problems on the boundary.